# How to config Nginx runs php on sub directories?

Tags: linux, nginx, configuration

I have 2 versions of portfolio website for 2 languages. I put them in 2  dir in the same root dir.

```
/root/
    |----vi/
    |----en/
    |----index.php
```

Then I config nginx as below:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 192.168.0.117;

    access_log /u01/projects/company/log/access.log main;
    error_log /u01/projects/company/log/error.log;
    set $rootLocation /u01/projects/company/;

    root $rootLocation;
    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~* /(vi|en)/admin(/|/.*\.php)$ {
       try_files $uri $uri/;
       gzip on;
       index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $rootLocation$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    include common.conf;#some fastcgi config
}
```

Look at `location`, I have `admin/` dir (and run php directly here) for every version. But when I access `192.168.0.117/en/admin/`, browser always redirect to `192.168.0.117/en/index.php`. What is wrong with this configuration? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
       try_files $uri $uri/;
```

By doing this you explicitly told it to redirect to `index.php`. A trailing `/` in a `try_files` means to try the value of the `index` directive.

In a PHP-FPM `location` this should instead be:

```
       try_files $uri =404;
```